# filter queryset for multiple models in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset, drf-queryset

- I'm implementing a search feature where I'm matching keys from the description. and also matching media if description and media type of `['mp4','mkv','mov','avi']` match so the condition is satisfied.
- So I have tried many methods but didn't find an efficient way. to make it possible without for loop.
- I want to use those together.

  - description and media type `['mp4','mkv','mov','avi']`

  ```
  postinlang_queryset = PostInLanguages.objects.filter(description__contains=search_name)
  media_type_query_set = LanguageMedia.objects.filter(content_type__contains ['mp4','mkv','mov','avi'])
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible without for loop.Just follow the following script:

```
postinlang_queryset = PostInLanguages.objects.filter(description__contains=search_name)
media_type_query_set = LanguageMedia.objects.filter(content_type__in=['mp4','mkv','mov','avi'])
```

**N.B: `content_type__in=['mp4','mkv','mov','avi']` If we pass an empty list then it will never throw exceptions but return empty queryset**

Comment: OK, Thanks dude, actually I wanted to use to together like
`PostInLanguages.objects.filter(description__contains=search_name, LanguageMedia.objects.filter(content_type__in=['mp4','mkv','mov','avi']))`

Comment: Could you please share the code for `PostInLanguages` & `LanguageMedia` models?

Comment: OK, [here You can find](https://linkode.org/#gJuFOpxrQ5Qhq9ZcTPusn1)